# Cornerstone SVN Error - Cant commit files

Tags: svn, version-control, cornerstone

Do users under passwd in subversion have certain permissions?

I can download all the files from my subversion repository using Cornerstone on mac.

But, if I make a change to a file and try to commit the file back to the repository...

Cornerstone gives me this:

```
Description : You are not authorized to access the files in the repository.
 Suggestion : You might be required to provide a user name and password when prompted before being allowed to access the repository.

Technical Information
=====================

      Error : V4AuthorizationError
  Exception : ZSVNAuthorizationException

Causal Information
==================

Description : Commit failed (details follow):
     Status : 170001
       File : subversion/libsvn_client/commit.c, 867

Description : Authorization failed
     Status : 170001
       File : subversion/svnserve/serve.c, 167
```

It doesnt prompt me for a username and password...

Anyone??

Answer (score 21):

I ran into the same issue and found the fix. You have to tell your keychain file that it's okay for the Cornerstone application to use the keychain file (do this manually).

First, go to Utilities--> Keychain Access.

Second, find the cornerstone keychain file. Should be a login keychain and the name should start with "Cornerstone."

Third, Right click the keychain file and click on "Get info."

Fourth, In the window that pops up, select the Access Control Tab.

Fifth, click the radio button that says "Allow all applications to access this item.

Enter your password, save changes.

Sixth, go back to cornerstone and reenter your username and password for the repository. Save changes.

Seventh, Commit the changes you were trying to commit.

Eighth, leave me some love at Lawsonry.com. =)

Comment: +1, this had been bugging me ever since installing Mountain Lion on a separate partition and manually transferring my keychain from Lion (Migration assistant had the same problem).

Answer (score 7):

Just delete the password saved by cornerstone on your keychain. It should work.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem on Cornerstone 2.02(i think). There is a bug with keychain option. To fix this you have to **unmark *save name and password in my keychain*** check box in **Add/Edit Repository** option. You will have to enter password every time though, but that's the price for making it work.

Comment: Look below where Lawsonry has a better solution to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

if you cannot unmark save name and password in my keychain checkbox, you'd better delete them manually. From Mac Finder, Go --> Ultities--> Keychain Access --> delete what you need here.

Answer (score 0):

Please take care that URLs in SVN are case-sensitive, so kindly remove the repository and add it again with the exact URL.

Please follow the screenshots, this should fix your issue.

[image: Deleting the current repository]

[image: Adding the repository again]

[image: Typing the case-sensitive repository name]